# Which is the best way to parse the JSON response?

Tags: android, json

I have tried to use the JSON in the android but it seems to be very limited for building and parsing. since you need to give static strings to get the data? any good library for pasing JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Google provided library for the same which is GSON. you can get it from google repository and embed in your project and use it from tutorial only.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 3):

The Android library ships with the simple [JSON-java](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)-library, which does a gread job for creating an parsing JSON.

If you want it to be even easier, you can use [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Examples on how to use it can be found on the project page.

Comment: can you give me links to the using GSON in Android tutorials plz

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide This does not differ from Android to normal Java SE

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).